# "to there" or "to...there"

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to write "to there" instead of the standard "to...there"?

E.g.: "For the walls of the room a blue color was chosen, to there create a cozy atmosphere"

To me it sounds old-english-fashioned and cool, but it also might just be wrong.

Comment: _There_ doesn't seem necessary at all. Where else would the atmosphere be created if not in the room? (Grammatically it's OK but seems very formal and archaic.)

Comment: Infinitives don't generally insert adverbs between the _to_ and the verb. So, no, it's not possible -- at least in this construction.

Comment: @JohnLawler Isn't the problem with "there" specifically? We can add other adverbs in that position in similar constructions, e.g.: "More throw-pillows were added gradually, to eventually create a cozy atmosphere."

Comment: Hm...  _There to create_ is OK, if florid. _To there create_ is still strained, but is sounds like an attempted variant -- imitating what the author might believe about the way people used to talk. _Eventually_ works because it refers specifically to manner and modifies the verb directly. _There_, or other locatives, on the other hand, are not necessary to specify  because they're presupposed -- everything happens at some time, in some place, and under some circumstances -- negating these negates the sentence, and they have different affordances.

Comment: The sentence is dodgy. I have undodgied it:  A blue color was chosen for the walls of the room to create a cozy atmosphere **in it** or **there**. to there; The color will go from here to there. [shown with hand gestures].

Comment: I agree that it sounds old fashioned, in fact so old fashioned that it's obsolete. If using florid and clumsy antique English is cool in your group then use it, but don't expect others to be impressed!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Yes, though it seems it's a bit of a historical usage.

From the US Supreme Court Corpus.

> In Gage v. Caraher, ubi supra, the Supreme Court of Illinois says: "
> Whatever may be the power of the court of chancery, where there are
> controverted titles, to restore by its decree the evidences of title
> in the respective parties as they were before the destruction of the
> record, and then, in its discretion, remit the parties to a court of
> law **to there try their titles**, it is manifest no such course was
> contemplated by the statute, or necessary in cases under it. (Gormley
> v. Clark; 134 U.S. 338; 1890)
>
> The court of civil appeals on June 28, 1907, handed down an opinion
> (103 S. w. 836 in which it declined to make an order directing the
> receiver in the Federal court to surrender possession, but did direct
> its receiver, in conjunction with the law officers of the state of
> Texas, to appear before the circuit court of the United States for the
> eastern district of Texas, and **to there urge the rights of the state
> and the prior jurisdiction of its courts over the property in
> question**, and to ask for such orders, decrees, and judgments as
> might be proper and necessary to protect that jurisdiction. (PALMER v.
> STATE OF TEXAS; 212 U.S. 118; 1909)
>
> The plaintiff was traveling to a land of promise, hoping **to there
> procure some occupation**, he knew not what, or to engage in some
> business, he knew not what. (NORTH AMERICAN TRANSP. & TRADING CO. v.
> MORRISON;     178 U.S. 262; 1900)

From the Corpus of Historical American English

> " And I, " said Mrs. Huntly, " now that I am blessed with my children,
> begin to feel anxious to see my native land again, **to there pass the
> remainder of my days**, and lay my bones with those that have gone
> before me. " (Leni-Leoti; or, Adventures in the Far West; Bennett,
> Emerson, 1822-1905)
>
> I must confess, however, that I can not detect that misrepresentation
> in my " Genesis of Species " which Mr. Wright seems **to there
> discover**. (St. George Mivart's letter on Specific Genesis, in reply
> to criticism of Chauncey Wright; North American Review: April 1872:
> 451-469)
>
> The Italian brass band, and the long procession of mourners first
> followed the casket out of the church **to there begin their long,
> sorrowful march to the grave**. (New Yorker: 1926-10-02: p. 17-21)

From The Corpus of the English House of Commons

> I beg to move, at the end of paragraph (c), to insert the words, And
> for enabling such officers to visit the office of each sub-committee
> at least once in each year and **to there investigate** and make a
> report to the Minister on any complaints which discharged soldiers and
> sailors and airmen or the wives or widows or dependants of sailors and
> soldiers and airmen may personally bring forward (Nov. 18 1918)
>
> The right hon: Gentleman asked whether any hon: Members of the
> Committee could suppose that he would be guilty of sending an informer
> into a Roman Catholic place of worship, **to there desecrate the
> Sacraments**, in order to get up charges against Irish people (28 May
> 1880)

I've not come across any uses past the early 20th century.

Answer (score 0):

John Lawler in a comment wrote:

> Hm...  *There to create* is OK, if florid. *To there create* is still strained, but is sounds like an attempted variant -- imitating what the author might believe about the way people used to talk. *Eventually* works because it refers specifically to manner and modifies the verb directly. *There*, or other locatives, on the other hand, are not necessary to specify  because they're presupposed -- everything happens at some time, in some place, and under some circumstances -- negating these negates the sentence, and they have different affordances.

Comment: I doubt anyone would ever start a sentence with "there to create" nowadays except perhaps in literary writing.

Answer (score 0):

I agree *there* is redundant in your sentence, but if you *must* express space once again, you could use ***therein*** at the end. Note, however, that it is dated, even archaic.

> For the walls of the room a blue color was chosen, to create a cozy atmosphere ***therein***.

***Therein***

> in or into a particular place, thing, etc.:
>
> - It is a thrilling tale of a haunted house and the ghosts therein. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/therein))